# What is this orange? pus growing on my Palm Tree?

Tags: fungus, palm

What is this orange pus growing on my Palm Tree?

We have two palm trees that are side by side, 1 is infected with this pus and the other is not. Is this a fungus? If so, which kind. Can I cure this issue, or will the tree solve the issue on it's own?

[image][image][image]

[HD Quality Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHJ23.jpg)

Comment: When you use the term 'pus' is it because the orange stuff feels soggy or its dripping? Did the palm flower this year? Is the plant otherwise healthy?

Comment: soggy I guess? I didn't investigate that much to be honest. It's like an orange film that can easily wipe away. I don't think our Sago has ever "Flowered" It seems pretty healthy otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the female sago palm flowers, the 'flower', which looks nothing like the usual idea of a flower (they look  more like orangy, ferny growths) is situated exactly where the orange fuzzy stuff is in your image, see here http://www.flowersofindia.net/catalog/slides/Sago%20Palm.html.  Since the tree is otherwise healthy, this may be the remains of flowering - unless you have a male sago nearby that also flowered, no seeds will have been produced.

Just keep an eye on the overall health of the tree till this has gone; you can wipe away any soggy bits as they degenerate if they are soggy, otherwise, they should just disappear on their own.